# Gnome Desktop Freezes after waking up from suspend

Tags: 20.04, gnome, suspend

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS with gnome 40.4.0 and I have a problem where when I wake my laptop up after it suspends, there is about a 50% chance that the show applications button on my taskbar will pop up in the middle of my taskbar location and it refuses to go away. If I click on it or if I press my super key my laptop will pull up the all applications screen and I am unable to close it unless I sign out and sign back in (reboot and shut downs work as well). Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

open Setting Menu
see screenshot =
[image]